# Size input text inside of table using bootstrap's classes

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, html-table

I have the code below where I'm trying to size a text input element using bootstrap's classes. However, I cannot get the thing to size down. I want it to be smaller on desktop, instead of taking up a massive amount of room.

```
<div class="container White_BG">
<div class="row" style="margin-left:0;margin-right:0;">
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">

<h1>Quickly place your order with this form.</h1>
<h2>Please enter the item numbers that you wish to order; once you add to the cart, then you will be able to change the quantity of those items ordered.</h2>

<div class="table-responsive">
    <form method="post" name="QuickOrderMulti">
        <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-hover">
            <tr>
                <th>Item #</th>
                <th>Quantity</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>Subtotal</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="col-lg-2">
                        <input type="text">
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text">
                </td>
                <td>

                </td>
                <td>

                </td>
                <td>

                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</div>

</div>
</div>
</div>
```

The offending line is:

```
<td>
    <div class="col-lg-2">
        <input type="text">
    </div>
</td>
```

I tried using the `col-lg-2` to make it only take up 2 grid columns, so maybe it'd be smaller. But no such luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than surrounding it in a div, try making the input with the chosen class.

e.g.

```
<input class="col-lg-2" type="text">
```

Comment: Ok, that made my input much smaller. But the entire field area is still large. I'm trying to shrink the entire area that's even containing the input. As you can see here: http://i.imgur.com/J0S2Waq.png

Comment: That might be to do with sizing your <td>'s and <tr>'s. Could you got to http://jsfiddle.net and post your code there then send the link so we can see a bit clearer as to what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: User Firebug oder Chrome (right mouse - click) - show element.
Then you can try witch class or Id you need to change.
https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/elements?hl=de